The arithmetic-geometric mean of Gauss
The arithmetic-geometric mean of Gauss.
Let $0 < a < b$. We define the two sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$ as follows:
$a_0 = a, b_0 = b, a_{n+1} = (a_n b_n)^{1/2}, b_{n+1} = \frac{a_n + b_n}{2}$
Prove that $b_{n+1} − a_{n+1} = \frac{(b_n − a_n)^2}{8b_{n+2}}$.
This is a question given to me as a challenge by a friend. There were three parts, I was able to do the rest parts, however, I am unable to think about this one. I tried induction, however the expressions were too ugly and long to write here. If any hints could be given, that would be appreciated.

I think your friend gave you an easy challenge.
By the way $b_{n+1}^{2} - a_{n+1}^{2} = (\frac{a_{n}+b_{n}}{2})^{2} - a_{n}b_{n} = (\frac{a_{n}-b_{n}}{2})^{2}
\\ \implies (b_{n+1} - a_{n+1})(b_{n+1} + a_{n+1}) = (\frac{a_{n}-b_{n}}{2})^{2}$
Also observe that $b_{n+2} = \frac{a_{n+1}+b_{n+1}}{2}$.
So $(b_{n+1} - a_{n+1}) = \frac{(a_{n}-b_{n})^{2}}{8b_{n+2}}$

Thank you! I agree, now I feel like a fool for not noticing!

I was just joking :)
